# Python re.sub(): how to substitute all 'u' or 'U's with 'you'

Tags: python, regex

I am doing some text normalization using python and regular expressions. I would like to substitute all 'u'or 'U's with 'you'. 
Here is what I have done so far:

```
import re
text = 'how are u? umberella u! u. U. U@ U# u '
print re.sub (' [u|U][s,.,?,!,W,#,@ (^a-zA-Z)]', ' you ', text)
```

The output I get is:

```
how are you  you berella you  you  you  you  you  you
```

As you can see the problem is that 'umberella' is changed to 'berella'. Also I want to keep the character that appears after a 'u'. For example I want 'u!' to be changed to 'you!'. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and what is the best way to write the regular expression?

Comment: The question isn't actually about how to do the substitution; that's the only part OP got right (use `re.sub`). The question is actually why the substitution replaces the entire match (it should use lookarounds instead), with a separate concern about how to actually write the character classes).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Firstly, why doesn't your solution work. You mix up a lot of concepts. Mostly [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with other ones. In the first character class you use `|` which stems from [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). In character classes you don't need the pipe. Just list all characters (and character ranges) you want:

```
[Uu]
```

Or simply write `u` if you use the case-insensitive modifier. If you write a pipe there, the character class will actually match pipes in your subject string.

Now in the second character class you use the comma to separate your characters for some odd reason. That does also nothing but include commas into the matchable characters. `s` and `W` are probably supposed to be the built-in character classes. Then escape them! Otherwise they will just match literal `s` and literal `W`. But then `\W` already includes everything else you listed there, so a `\W` alone (without square brackets) would have been enough. And the last part `(^a-zA-Z)` also doesn't work, because it will simply include `^`, `(`, `)` and all letters into the character class. The negation syntax only works for entire character classes like `[^a-zA-Z]`.

What you actually want is to assert that there is no letter in front or after your `u`. You can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that. The advantage is that they won't be included in the match and thus won't be removed:

```
r'(?<![a-zA-Z])[uU](?![a-zA-Z])'
```

Note that I used a raw string. Is generally good practice for regular expressions, to avoid problems with escape sequences.

These are negative lookarounds that make sure that there is no letter character before or after your `u`. This is an important difference to asserting that there is a non-letter character around (which is similar to what you did), because the latter approach won't work at the beginning or end of the string.

Of course, you can remove the spaces around `you` from the replacement string.

If you don't want to replace `u` that are next to digits, you can easily include the digits into the character classes:

```
r'(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])[uU](?![a-zA-Z0-9])'
```

And if for some reason an adjacent underscore would also disqualify your `u` for replacement, you could include that as well. But then the character class coincides with the built-in `\w`:

```
r'(?<!\w)[uU](?!\w)'
```

Which is, in this case, equivalent to EarlGray's `r'\b[uU]\b'`.

As mentioned above you can shorten all of these, by using the case-insensitive modifier. Taking the first expression as an example:

```
re.sub(r'(?<![a-z])u(?![a-z])', 'you', text, flags=re.I)
```

or

```
re.sub(r'(?<![a-z])u(?![a-z])', 'you', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

depending on your preference.

I suggest that you do some reading through the tutorial I linked several times in this answer. The explanations are very comprehensive and should give you a good headstart on regular expressions, which you will probably encounter again sooner or later.

Comment: Your answer was outstanding. Thanks!

Comment: this is an interesting general technique, but I'd rather use \b to match a word break

Comment: @Sam I just wanted to make sure that the implications of using `\b` were clear (in particular, that digits and underscores are in included).

Comment: What does `?<` do?

Comment: @NeilAgarwal Do you mean `(?<!...)`? It's a negative lookbehind. There's a link to a tutorial on lookarounds in the answer, I don't think I could explain it better myself (at least not within the space of a comment).

Answer (score 15):

Use a special character `\b`, which matches empty string at the beginning or at the end of a word:

```
print re.sub(r'\b[uU]\b', 'you', text)
```

spaces are not a reliable solution because there are also plenty of other punctuation marks, so an abstract character `\b` was invented to indicate a word's beginning or end.

Comment: except that `'\b'` is the same as `'\x08'`. you need to escape (`'\\b'` or `r'\b'`)!

Comment: This is the output of your code on 'text' as I defined in the code:

how are u? umberella u! u. U. U@ U# u

So none of the u's were changed to you.

Comment: @user823743 Yes, I forget `r` before my regular expression, as it was edited by Wooble (thanks!).

Comment: Note that `\b` is not an "abstract character" but a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (which will never consume any character, it's just a position). Also this might fail you if `u` is surrounded by digits or underscores (depending on desired behavior)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
    import re
    text = 'how are u? umberella u! u. U. U@ U# u '
    rex = re.compile(r'\bu\b', re.IGNORECASE)
    print(rex.sub('you', text))
```

It pre-compiles the regular expression and makes use of re.IGNORECASE so that we don't have to worry about case in our regular expression!  BTW, I love the funky spelling of umbrella! :-)

Answer (score 2):

it can also be achieved with below code

```
import re

text = 'how are u? umberella u! u. U. U@ U# u '
print (re.sub (r'[uU] ( [^a-z] )', r' you\1 ', text))
```

or

```
print (re.sub (r'[uU] ( [\s!,.?@#] )', r' you\1 ', text))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution I came up with was:

```
re.sub(r'([uU]+(.)?\s)',' you ', text)
```