# Python substitute with numbering inside patterns

Tags: python, loops, substitution

I'm trying to come up with a python script to automatically number footnotes in pandoc markdown. Given input like this:

> This is a testing document for testing purposes only.[^0] This is a testing
>   document for testing purposes only. This is a testing document for testing
>   purposes only.[^121][^5] This is a testing document for testing purposes
>   only.
>
> [^0]: Footnote contents.
>
> [^0]: Footnote contents.
>
> [^0]: Footnote contents.

It should produce output like this:

> This is a testing document for testing purposes only.[^1] This is a testing
>   document for testing purposes only. This is a testing document for testing
>   purposes only.[^2][^3] This is a testing document for testing purposes
>   only.
>
> [^1]: Footnote contents.
>
> [^2]: Footnote contents.
>
> [^3]: Footnote contents.

I've been able to make the basic functionality work, but I'm stuck on how to cover the case of two footnotes on one line. Perhaps the loops should not be line based? Or should I opt for some sort of nested loop, replacing nth occurence of a pattern (which, as I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182546/how-to-replace-the-nth-appearance-of-a-needle-in-a-haystack-python) question is not trivial)?

And since I'm trying to learn as much as possible from this, feel free to drop any comments or pointers for further improvements. Thanks!

Here is the script I have so far:

```
import re
from sys import argv

script, first = argv

i=0
n=0
buff = ''

# open the file specified through the first argument
f = open(first, 'rU')

for line in f:
    if re.search(r'\[\^[0-9]+\]:', line):
        i += 1
        line2 = re.sub(r'\[\^[0-9]+\]:', '[^' + str(i) + ']:', line)
        buff += line2

    elif re.search(r'\[\^[0-9]+\]', line):
        n += 1
        line3 = re.sub(r'\[\^[0-9]+\]', '[^' + str(n) + ']', line)
        buff += line3

    else:
        buff += line

print buff

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_text="""This is a testing document for testing purposes only.[^0] This is a testing document for testing purposes only. This is a testing document for testing purposes only.[^121][^5] This is a testing document for testing purposes only.

[^0]: Footnote contents.

[^0]: Footnote contents.

[^0]: Footnote contents."""


num_notes = len(re.findall("\[\^\d+\]",my_text))
i = -1 
def do_sub(m):
    global i
    i+=1
    return "[^%d]"%(i if i < num_notes//2 else i-num_notes//2)

re.sub("\[\^\d+\]",do_sub,my_text)
```

I think will do what you want

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Tried to `print my_text` after the last line or assigned the last line to a variable and then print it, but it always prints the original (non-numbered) contents. And I have trouble understanding the `return` line (the part in parentheses) so I'm not really able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: that's because re. Sub returns a new string

Comment: Okay, but when I do `print re.sub("\[^\d+\]",do_sub,my_text)` (analogically to how it's done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748674/how-to-use-re-sub), for example), I still get the original unnumbered input. Why is that?

Comment: Just tried it, but there is no difference. I would paste exactly what I did, but that exceeds the allowed length of a comment. Maybe I should mention that I use Python 2.7.9 ? (the default one on Ubuntu 15.04)

Comment: oh dang you are totally right ... I forgot to escape the `^` it should be `\^` ... see this ideone sketch http://ideone.com/9R8c3m ..editing answer to correct it now

Comment: Oh, I also missed that. Now it's working!
Would you care to explain the `return` line? Pretty pretty please :)